# javax bean validation for members of Abstract class?

Tags: java, javabeans, abstract

I am a newbie to javax bean validation.

I have an abstract class that some other classes are extending. Does it make sense to provide bean validation for data members of the parent abstract class or is it better to provide validation for the data members in the child classes extending this class?